# Rails I18n: Can I implement client-specific scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm building a multi-tenant web app. Let's say I have a home page with the following:

`%h1= t :welcome`

I also have `en.yml` with the following:

```
en:
  default:
    welcome: 'Welcome!'
  my_client:
    welcome: 'Hey, we are My Client, we do this and that'
```

I would like my translation to look-up client-specific translation first, and if not found, fall back to the default one. Is there a way to do this with Rails?

I know Rails has several places where it would look up things like model attribute names, so there must be some kind of a way to add a lookup path/scope, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think if you have the client's version on a separate yml file, and read that after the default yml, then the former will override the latter.

Comment: Or, perhaps you can handle the client's version on a par with a language, and let the default English be the fallback.

Comment: .yml files are probably the wrong way to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out "there's a gem for that"
https://github.com/ElMassimo/i18n_multitenant